# How to disable Amazon SES when using Spring Cloud AWS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-ses

For using Amazon S3, I have added `spring-cloud-aws-context` and `spring-cloud-starter-aws` in my `pom.xml`.

I was able to implement the push and retrieve from Amazon S3 but now when I'm trying to send an email from my application, I'm getting this error:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Missing required header 'From'. (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 3611418a-7680-11e5-b874-71fbd9180e4c); message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Missing required header 'From'. (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 3611418a-7680-11e5-b874-71fbd9180e4c)
```

It seems that my `JavaMailSender` implementation is now trying to use Amazon SES instead of the regular `org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl`.
I'm not able to find with properties or annotation I should use to force Spring to NOT use Amazon SES (FYI, I'm using Spring Boot)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if we take a look to the `MailSenderAutoConfiguration` source code, will see this:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingClass(name = "org.springframework.cloud.aws.mail.simplemail.SimpleEmailServiceJavaMailSender")
public MailSender simpleMailSender(AmazonSimpleEmailService amazonSimpleEmailService) {
    return new SimpleEmailServiceMailSender(amazonSimpleEmailService);
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass(Session.class)
public JavaMailSender javaMailSender(AmazonSimpleEmailService amazonSimpleEmailService) {
    return new SimpleEmailServiceJavaMailSender(amazonSimpleEmailService);
}
```

So, both these bean delegate to the `AmazonSimpleEmailService`.
Not sure why is that the problem for you, but if you'd like do not use `SES`, but just your own `javaMailSender` bean, consider to exclude `MailSenderAutoConfiguration` from `@SpringBootApplication`

Exclusion can be done using an application property so that it can be toggled based on environment: 
`spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderAutoConfiguration`